# Visual Studio not ignoring generated code specified in editorConfig

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sonarlint, editorconfig

I've got an project with code from an custom code generator that i wrote.
The generated code is named *something*_gen.cs
Although in the editorconfig i specified that all *_gen.cs files should be ignored, SonarLint still analyses the gen files.

According to the [SonarLint Documentation](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-visualstudio/wiki/Choosing-which-C%23-or-VB.NET-rules-to-run-in-Standalone-mode#how-can-i-configure-the-rules-cvbnet-rules-to-use) the Files shouldn't be analysed.

The .editorconfig looks like this

```
root = true
[*_gen.cs]
exclude = true
generated_code = true

[*.cs]
#Spaces and indents
indent_style=space
indent_size=4

and so on...
```

The Project Layout Looks like this

```
Project Root
|-Project.sln
|-.editorconfig
|Module A
 |-codeA.cs
 |-codeB.cs
 |-code_gen.cs
 |-ModuleA.csproj
|Module B
 |-codeA.cs
 |-codeB.cs
 |-code_gen.cs
 |-ModuleB.csproj
```

Answer (score 1):

EditorConfig doesn't understand name postfixes. It is possible to define a file group with file extension (`*.gen`) or folder (`gen/*`).

Documentation: https://editorconfig.org/#file-format-details.